# Referenced assembly 'Twilio, Version=5.68.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have a strong name. Twilio

Tags: c#, twilio

I cannot seem to get passed this error when trying to use the Twilio nuget package.

Referenced assembly 'Twilio, Version=5.68.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have a strong name.

I have tried everything I can find, which is very little, on here.

Has anyone out there been able to get passed this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Your assembly has a [strong name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/strong-naming) and is signed with a key. As such, it can only reference assemblies that are strong-named too. The Twilio assembly is not strong-named, hence the problem.

Either disable signing your assembly in project properties or build the Twilio assembly yourself and sign it with a key. The code can be found on [Github](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp), so you can create a fork and adjust this to your needs.

Comment: Let me also add that you don't necessarily need to compile the project yourself.
Instead you can get the package from NuGet, use tools like Sn.exe (Strong Name Tool) to generate a key to sign, and use tools like Ildasm.exe (IL Disassembler) to disassemble the Twilio DLL and Ilasm.exe (IL Assembler) to re-assemble the Twilo DLL and sign it with a strong name.
You can put this all together in a script, even MSBuild script, to seamlessly generate strongly named DLL versions of existing DLLs.
https://codeasp.net/articles/-net/92/how-to-add-a-strong-name-to-an-existing-dll-or-assembly

Comment: @Swimburger thanks for your comment, yes that's also a good way